# React ApolloClient mutations

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to make a form to create a new announcement, but I get error:

`Invariant Violation: Argument of undefined passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document`

This is my first time using GraphQL and Apollo, so I don't know exactly what I should do.

***CreateAnnouncement component:***

```
import { compose, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { addAnnouncement as addAnnouncementMutation } from '../../../mutations/Announcements.gql';
import { announcement as announcementQuery } from '../../../queries/Announcements.gql';

class CreateAnnouncement extends React.Component {
...
}

export default compose(
  graphql(announcementQuery, {
    options: ({ match }) => ({
      variables: {
        _id: match.params._id,
      },
    }),
  }),

  ***THE ERROR POINTS NEXT LINE***

  graphql(addAnnouncementMutation, {
    name: 'addAnnouncement',
  }),
)(CreateAnnouncement);
```

***'../../../mutations/Announcements.gql'***

```
#import "../fragments/Announcements.gql"

mutation addAnnouncement($title: String!, $description: String, $date: String!) {
  addAnnouncement(title: $title, description: $description, date: $date) {
    ...AnnouncementAttributes
  }
}
```

***"../fragments/Announcements.gql"***

```
fragment AnnouncementAttributes on Announcement {
  _id
  title
  description
  date
  createdAt
  updatedAt
}
```

Comment: What babel plugin or webpack loader are you using to be able to import `.gql` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this problem. The reason was that there was only one "add" mutation in file.

I added a new one mutation and it worked.

```
#import "../fragments/Announcements.gql"

mutation addAnnouncement($title: String!, $description: String, $date: String!) {
  addAnnouncement(title: $title, description: $description, date: $date) {
    ...AnnouncementAttributes
  }
}

mutation updateAnnouncement($_id: String!, $title: String, $description: String, $date: String) {
  updateAnnouncement(_id: $_id, title: $title, description: $description, date: $date) {
    ...AnnouncementAttributes
  }
}
```

You also need to define this mutation in resolvers and schema.